# How to combine pgfplots and colormap for line-plot

Tags: pgfplots, color

My code so far

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{
/pgfplots/colormap={bright}{rgb255=(0,0,0) rgb255=(78,3,100) rgb255=(2,74,255)
    rgb255=(255,21,181) rgb255=(255,113,26) rgb255=(147,213,114) rgb255=(230,255,0)
    rgb255=(255,255,255)}
```

I've just copied this code from the manual. But how can I now tell my plot to use this colormap?

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{Plots/dat.txt} \datA
\begin{axis}[
axis y line*=left,
axis x line*=top,
ylabel near ticks,
xlabel near ticks,
xlabel=Current in A,
ylabel=Voltage in V,
every x tick label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
every y tick label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
]
\addplot [mark=none] table [x index = 0, y index = 1] from \datA ; % ,
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

The plot is created correctly but all lines are just black.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `\addplot [mark=none] ...`, the effect is that `mark=none` completely overwrites any style given by the active `cycle list`. That means in turn that the default line style of TikZ is used, which is just a black line. You want `\addplot +[mark=none]`, where the `+` indicates that `mark=none` is appended to the style given by the cycle list.

That is just part of the answer though. In the code you show you have only defined a `color map`, you haven't actually used it. Add `colormap name=bright` to the `axis` options to activate it. But the `colormap` doesn't directly influence the style of line plots, in order to pick colours from the `colormap` for line plots, add for example `cycle list={[of colormap]}` to the `axis` options. Because the `bright` map you defined has eight colours, this cycle list will get eight colours as well.

If you want a given number of equally spaced samples from the `colormap`, you can use e.g. `cycle list={[samples of colormap={20} of bright]}` to get 20 samples (you don't have to specify `colormap=bright` in this case). You can also get non-equally spaced samples, by using e.g. `cycle list={[colors of colormap={0,300,600,1000}]}`. You supply a list of values between 0 and 1000, where 0 is the start of the map, and 1000 is the end.

All this `colormap` vs. `cycle list` stuff is described in the `pgfplots` manual, at the end of section *4.7.7 Cycle Lists – Options Controlling Line Styles*, page 219. (In the manual for version 1.16 of `pgfplots`, dated 2018-3-28.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{
colormap={bright}{rgb255=(0,0,0) rgb255=(78,3,100) rgb255=(2,74,255)
    rgb255=(255,21,181) rgb255=(255,113,26) rgb255=(147,213,114) rgb255=(230,255,0)
    rgb255=(255,255,255)}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis y line*=left,
axis x line*=top,
ylabel near ticks,
xlabel near ticks,
xlabel=Current in A,
ylabel=Voltage in V,
every x tick label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
every y tick label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
colormap name=bright, % activate the defined colormap
cycle list={[of colormap]},
every axis plot/.append style={mark=none,ultra thick} % set options for all plots
]
\addplot {x};
\addplot {x+1};
\addplot {x+2};
\addplot {x+3};
\addplot {x+4};
\addplot {x+5};
\addplot {x+6};
\addplot {x+7}; % white, so not visible
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Really helped a lot. I've already looked at the doc but I wasn't able to figure out what to define inside the axis-block. Another question. When I write cycle list={[samples of colormap={20} of bright]} and I doesn't define the map via \pgfplotsset I get an error, that the argument bright ist not a valid colormap.

Comment: @vogs Well yes. That colormap isn't defined by default, so naturally you can't sample from it.

Comment: I see. But honestly, none of them looks really nice to me. I would prefer some kind of 'rainbow' colors. For me e.g. this could be the color scheme 'hot' from the manual. But if I use 'hot' but then the colors repeat every 3 lines.

Comment: @vogs So add the definition of the `hot` colormap (instead of `bright`), and use for example `cycle list={[samples of colormap={10} of hot]}`. Then the colours reapeat every 10 lines. Change the number (10) as you see fit.

Comment: I have now just following two lines:  cycle list={[samples of colormap={8} of hot]}, every axis plot/.append style={mark=none}. But the 8 colors are so close. Like yellow, dark yellow, light orange. One can't distinguish them.

Comment: @vogs Then perhaps you're going about this the wrong way. You could define your own custom cycle list (see `pgfplots` manual section 4.7.7, as mentioned in my answer). Then you can set exactly the colours (and markers, and line widths etc.) you want. Or perhaps one of the schemes in the `colorbrewer` library of `pgfplots` is adequate. For example add `\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}` to the preamble, and `cycle list/Set1-8` to the `axis` options. See the `pgfplots` manual for an overview of the other available schemes.

Comment: I now made my own colorlist with \pgfplotsset{
 colormap={mycolormap}{rgb255=...}} then in the figure section I use  colormap name=mycolormap, 
 cycle list={[of mycolormap]}, but I get always the error now: Package pgfplots Error: Unknown key 'of mycolormap'. Is this a colormap name? Maybe you need to write \pgfplotsset{of mycolormap} first?. ] What am I doing wrong again?

Comment: @vogs You're supposed to write `colormap name=mycolormap, cycle list={[of colormap]}`. I.e. in the argument to `cycle list` you write `of colormap`, not `of nameofwhatevercolormapyoumade`.